# Removing uncessary space in Latex

Tags: spacing

I want to remove some vertical spacing in my page. Actually, the page is formatted automatically through this command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Conclusions}
\input{tex/08_conclusion.tex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%              APPENDIX             %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%             REFERENCES            %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagebreak
\addtotoc{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Top of the page:
[image]

The output is shown in this way:
[image]

Comment: Did you try addìng the  `\raggedbottom`  directive in your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`)?

Comment: do you have some large object (a tabular or a graphic) following this text that can 't float?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks this resolves the problem !

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your answer, no I don't have any graphic and with using \raggedbottom, the problem is resolved !

Comment: You must have _something_ at the top of the next page.

Comment: But you must do something to force latex to stretch the text like this, you should better find out what, as raggedbottom gives pages of different height.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have only the chapter name in big caracters, I updated the question, please take a look at the new image

Comment: no, what do you have on the *next* page is what matters. You can't have the start of chapter 8 there, your current page already shows chapter 8 in the header.

Comment: now I understand you, I think because there is a \pagebreak after this chapter, I updated the command for you, so please take a look

Comment: Where have you seen that `\pagebreak` would be a good command to use? Genuine question, there might be some online documentation that needs a friendly update request.

Comment: @daleif It was already inputted in the template that I am using, this is my first work with Latex, that's why I am asking

Comment: Then the whoever made that template owes you a beer (or similar). That macro should be used with extreme care. Normally the macro to use is `\newpage` which does not stretch. The again, why are you even changing the page here?

Comment: @daleif thank you, this resolves the problem completly and also "\raggedbottom" is not needed, the change of the page because the next page should be written in a new chapter (new page), I didn't only understand why the author of this template use \pagebreak instead of \newpage only in the last switch between the chapters, specifically between the chapter "Conclusion" and the chapter "Bibliography"

Comment: Unless you've done something, `\chapter ` and `\chapter*` automatically starts a new page.

Comment: @daleif ah OK, that's why in all the chapter, nothing is used, tjhe jumping to the new page was performed by default, only between the last two chapters, \pagebreak is used